# InfoPath 2010: Populating drowdown from SQL on load form

Tags: infopath, sql-server

I have a data connection to SQL database already set and for the form to query the database on form load. In the dropdown list property I have it pulling from an external data source and in the entries, value and display name I have select the correct columns.

When I go to preview the dropdown is blank. I'm not finding anything online to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have a lot of information to go off with your question, perhaps screenshots of your data connections and such could help us be more specific.

Microsoft does have a tutorial on how to use SQL data connections in InfoPath (it's for 2007, but still applies): http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-a-data-connection-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-HP010092823.aspx.  You might run through the tutorial to ensure you didn't miss anything.

Another note: SQL connections don't work with an InfoPath Web Form.  You would need to use web services to interact with your data in that scenario.